# Perl string matching and data extraction

Tags: regex, perl

I am working on a data extraction program but I can't seem to get this one portion of the data log to work when it comes to trying to determine the die position on the wafer.

```
    &write_device_results($sbin, $hbin, $diex, $diey, $site, $time, @testdata);
} elsif($line =~ m/"Site 1: W"(\d+)(\d+)/) { # <---- THIS IS NOT WORKING
    $diex = $1;
    $diey = $2;
} elsif($line =~ m/Site (\d+) has \w+. Binned to bin (\d+)\((\d+)\)/) { <- THIS WORKS
    $site = $1;
    $sbin = $2;
    $hbin = $3;
```

The line I am trying to extract the data from is this:

> Site 1: W0,0 <--- The first 0 is the $diex position, the second is the $diey position.

This line I am able to extract the data from:

> Site 1 has FAILED. Binned to bin 24(23)

Any thoughts on how I extract the 0,0 data from the above would be great.

Comment: Figured it out partially... } elsif($line =~ m/Site 1: W(\d+),(\d+)/) {  will suck out the 0,0 from Site 1: W0,0      However, it does not match negative numbers... so I'm still looking

Comment: Site 1: W-1,-1    My above elsif statement only extracts 0 and positive numbers. I need negative numbers extracted as well.

Comment: Okay, figured this out after some additional web searching.

Comment: The expression I needed to match is as follows:                                 } elsif($line =~ m/Site 1: W(-?\d+),(-?\d+)/) {
 $diex = $1;
 $diey = $2;